# Cisco 1921 private LAN can't access internet on WAN interface

Tags: cisco, routing, router, nat, wan

I have a Cisco 1921 Router with an private LAN interface, and a public WAN interface. I also have two VPN tunnels configured, one to another colo location and one to AWS. From the LAN side of this router, I can access our other colo, but can't access anything on the internet through the WAN interface. From the CLI of the router, I can ping public internet addresses, but not from the LAN side. I'm fairly new to Cisco's, can someone help me out with what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Below is our current config:

```
    cisco-1-c#sho run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 5261 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 12:35:42 est Wed Aug 3 2016 by chris
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:13:38 est Tue Aug 2 2016 by chris
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:13:38 est Tue Aug 2 2016 by chris
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname cisco-1-c
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$M5cQ$CnHaSbm3Y609.UyyO4uQk.
enable password pqBwmuzM5HwKWUc3
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone est -4 0
!
ip cef
!
!
!
no ip dhcp conflict logging
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.1.9.1 10.1.9.200
ip dhcp ping packets 10
ip dhcp ping timeout 100
!
ip dhcp pool 365
 network 10.1.9.0 255.255.255.0
 domain-name sidecartechnologies.com
 default-router 10.1.9.1
 dns-server 10.1.11.27 10.1.9.0
 lease infinite
!
!
!
ip domain name sidecartechnologies.com
ip name-server 66.28.0.45
ip name-server 66.28.0.61
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FGL171525QB
!
!
username chris privilege 15 secret 4 jP26tUYnl6KctHh55eUO9/UgebW38DaXI1nRsos92PQ
username sidecaradmin privilege 15 secret 4 3wDP4cwei1UMG.WnceYEkjK2v8adDxeofNSHSHI3y1M
username adam privilege 15 password 0 1mxsuck5
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto keyring keyring-vpn-04d0c665-1
  local-address 38.122.23.162
  pre-shared-key address 54.210.103.217 key sT_bDVJbXn2vY8onWRFVnR2z5yiAkUu8
crypto keyring keyring-vpn-04d0c665-0
  local-address 38.122.23.12
  pre-shared-key address 52.203.180.41 key dulIUfC0AEgGInhqmB9MtnKZnY5zA8mM
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
!
crypto isakmp policy 200
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
 lifetime 28800
!
crypto isakmp policy 201
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
 lifetime 28800
crypto isakmp key iGX9sFJHfxQo address 70.34.227.146
crypto isakmp keepalive 10 10
crypto isakmp profile isakmp-vpn-04d0c665-0
   keyring keyring-vpn-04d0c665-0
   match identity address 52.203.180.41 255.255.255.255
   local-address 38.122.23.162
crypto isakmp profile isakmp-vpn-04d0c665-1
   keyring keyring-vpn-04d0c665-1
   match identity address 54.210.103.217 255.255.255.255
   local-address 38.122.23.162
!
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association replay window-size 128
!
crypto ipsec transform-set WCIT esp-des esp-sha-hmac
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-04d0c665-0 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-04d0c665-1 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec df-bit clear
!
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-04d0c665-0
 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
 set transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-04d0c665-0
 set pfs group2
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-04d0c665-1
 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
 set transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-04d0c665-1
 set pfs group2
!
!
crypto map WCITVPN 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 70.34.227.146
 set transform-set WCIT
 match address 150
!
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 169.254.44.102 255.255.255.252
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1387
 tunnel source 38.122.23.162
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel destination 52.203.180.41
 tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-04d0c665-0
!
interface Tunnel2
 ip address 169.254.45.178 255.255.255.252
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1387
 tunnel source 38.122.23.162
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel destination 54.210.103.217
 tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-04d0c665-1
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.9.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip nat enable
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 38.122.23.162 255.255.255.248
 ip nat inside
 ip nat enable
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 no mop enabled
 crypto map WCITVPN
!
router bgp 65000
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 169.254.44.101 remote-as 7224
 neighbor 169.254.44.101 timers 10 30 30
 neighbor 169.254.45.177 remote-as 7224
 neighbor 169.254.45.177 timers 10 30 30
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 0.0.0.0
  neighbor 169.254.44.101 activate
  neighbor 169.254.44.101 default-originate
  neighbor 169.254.44.101 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  neighbor 169.254.45.177 activate
  neighbor 169.254.45.177 default-originate
  neighbor 169.254.45.177 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 38.122.23.161
!
access-list 1 permit 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 10 permit 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 150 permit ip 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255 10.1.11.0 0.0.0.255
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password pqBwmuzM5HwKWUc3
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
ntp peer 0.us.pool.ntp.org prefer version 2
!
end

cisco-1-c#
```

The routing table:

```
Gateway of last resort is 38.122.23.161 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 38.122.23.161
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
C        10.1.9.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        10.1.9.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
B        10.10.0.0/16 [20/100] via 169.254.45.177, 2d00h
      38.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        38.122.23.160/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0
L        38.122.23.162/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0
         169.254.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        169.254.45.176/30 is directly connected, Tunnel2
L        169.254.45.178/32 is directly connected, Tunnel2
```

The tracepath from a server on the internal network to a public internet server (google.com in this case)

```
    [chris@db1-r2-c ~]$ tracepath 74.125.22.139
 1?: [LOCALHOST]     pmtu 1500
 1:  cisco-1-c.sidecartechnologies.com (10.1.9.1)           0.558ms
 1:  cisco-1-c.sidecartechnologies.com (10.1.9.1)           0.486ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
31:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
[chris@db1-r2-c ~]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You NAT is incorrect:

```
ip nat inside source list intranet pool external overload
!
```

You don't even have the pool which you are referencing in the NAT statement.

It should be something like:

```
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255
!
```

My example will translate source addresses in the `10.1.9.0/24` range which come in the `GigabitEthernet0/0` interface and leave through the `GigabitEthernet0/0/0` interface. The address on the `GigabitEthernet0/0/0` interface will be the one used for the above traffic leaving that interface.

---

**Edit:**

Below is what should work:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.9.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 38.122.23.162 255.255.255.248
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 no mop enabled
 crypto map WCITVPN
!
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255
!
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. I changed the the ip nat source to what you suggested (it seemed like exactly what I want to happen) as well as the access list.

I'm still getting the access-list 1 as:

access-list 1 permit 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0

I tried doing a no access-list 1 to remove it, which it did. When I entered in your suggestion, it still came up as that.

Comment: Ah I missed your update when I first tried to change my config. That seemed to take ok now.

However now I seem to have lost the IPSec VPN between colo's.

Comment: OK I will edit. Put your ACL 1 back to the way you originally had it, and I will use ACL 10.

Comment: That brought back the tunnel (hooray!). 

From the router I can ping google.com, but not from a server behind the router.

Comment: What is the server address?

Comment: I am also confused by the second static route. It seems that the first static, default route would cover the second route. Is there a particular reason for the second static route? It is also not a good idea to route to the interface as you do in the second static route.

Comment: Are you talking about the 150 access list? I thought I needed that to go over our vpn tunnel to the other colo. 

The server address I'm using to ping out to the internet is 10.1.9.2

Comment: No, I mean the static routes: `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 38.xxx.xxx.161` and
`ip route 10.1.9.0 255.255.255.0 GigabitEthernet0/0/0 10`.

Comment: If I'm honest, and I am being so here, that was me fumbling my way through my first ever cisco router config, so I may have done that thinking I knew what I was doing and didn't. I'll remove it and see if that makes things better.

After removing that second route, it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that ping works on that server internally? Without being able to see the routing table, it is difficult to determine exactly where your traffic is going. If it comes through the inside interface, going out the outside interface, it should be translated. It may be that your routing table directs the traffic to one of the tunnels instead.

Comment: So, I can ping the internal gateway (10.1.9.2) and the external IP on that router. I can't ping to the routers next hop externally.

Our routing table looks like:

Comment: Gateway of last resort is 38.122.23.161 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 38.122.23.161
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
C        10.1.9.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        10.1.9.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
B        10.10.0.0/16 [20/100] via 169.254.45.177, 2d00h
      38.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        38.122.23.160/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0
L        38.122.23.162/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0

Comment: Try to run `traceroute` (`tracert` in Windows) from the server to the target address on the Internet. Edit the question with the results.

Comment: It looks like the NAT isn't working. Do you have `ip nat inside` and `ip nat outside` on the correct interfaces? I may help if you edit the question to show the current router configuration.

Comment: I missed the fact that you have the `ip nat enable` command on the outside interface. You are mixing two different NAT methods. Remove that command.

Comment: I just updated the question with the latest sho run, to help see where we're at now. Thanks for all the help so far Ron, I really appreciate it.

I just removed `ip nat enabled` on the external interface, should I remove on the internal one as well?

Comment: Remove the `ip nat enable` command from the interfaces. Also, you now seem to have the `ip nat inside` and `ip nat outside` command on the wrong interfaces. `inside` is for your LAN, and `outside` is for your WAN.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I used what you put in your edit, and now the tunnel dropped between colo's again, which killed my access to the server I was using to test.

Comment: Is the server on the `interface GigabitEthernet0/0` interface?

Comment: Yes it is. Gi0/0 is the internal LAN interface for the 10.1.9.0 network. Gi0/0/0 is the public facing interface.

Comment: I don't understand how you are losing connection to the server. Anything sourced from the server, not destined to an address in the `10.10.0.0/16` range, should go out the `GigabitEthernet0/0/0` interface, and that will translate the source address to `38.122.23.162`. If your host is anywhere in the `10.1.9.0/24` or `10.10.0.0/16` ranges, you should not lose access to the server.

Comment: Ah I think I see how it happened. I'm using server in the `10.1.11.0` range to access the server in the `10.1.9.0` range. That seems to make sense, right?  
  
`10.1.9.0` - Behind the cisco we're working on in Colo2  
`10.1.11.0` - Behind a different vendor router in Colo1  

Does that help ?

Comment: You need a route to the `10.1.11.0/24` network. How does that connect to the network? You should probably include that in the BGP advertisement from the site where it is. Since the router doesn't have a path to that network, it will use the default route. The NAT I gave you should work, but you need to fix your routes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. To get to the `10.1.11.0/24` network we go over one of the VPN tunnels. Specifically the `70.34.227.146` IPSec Tunnel. Unless I have that misconfigured too?

Comment: You could add a static route in this router, or the real solution is to advertise it from the router where it originates.

Comment: Thanks! I'll dig into getting BGP set up on the cisco, since that's what initiates the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common configuration.  You could almost copy and paste from Cisco's [LAN-to-LAN IPsec Tunnel Between Two Routers Configuration Example](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/1700-series-modular-access-routers/71462-rtr-l2l-ipsec-split.html).

In your case you have 3 locations and should nail up a full mesh - where each router has 2 VPN tunnels.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are able to ping ISP from router because a general when packet is initiated it will check from routing , natting and access-list , In this case public ip is reachable from router because default route pointing to ISP gateway is in place .

So in order to ping from LAN networks ,some modifications requires for NAT overload rule for mapping many to 1 public
IP address  .

`Router(config)# access-list 1 permit 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255`
`Router(config)#IP nat inside source list 1 interfàce gigabit Ethernet 0/0/0 0verload`

And make sure tell natting Machines which interface is outside and which interfàce is inside

`Router(config)#int gigabit Ethernet 0/0`
`Router(config)#ip nat inside`

`Router(config)#interface gigabit Ethernet 0/0/0`
`Router(config)#ip nat outside`